# How can I use the tor browser via selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, tor, selenium-webdriver-python

Hello can you tell me how to use the tor browser via selenium so far I have only found this:

```
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
with TorBrowserDriver('C:\Users\Brotb\Downloads\win (1)\vendor\tor-bundle') as driver:
    driver.get('https://google.com')
```

and this doesnt work
can somebody help me?